# Ember: Handling window resize within a component

Tags: ember.js

I have a component which renders a selection of images, and I have some CSS for a "hover mask" which then covers the image, displaying some information about that image when a user hovers over it.

The dimensions of the hover mask need to match those of the image when the app first loads, and when the window resizes.

Here's the basic mark up

```
<div class="call-out-item">
  <img src="......">
  <div class="hover-mask">Some info about this image</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.call-out-item {
  position:relative;
  display:none;
}

.call-out-item .hover-mask {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.call-out-item:hover .hover-mask {
   opacity: .95;
   background: rgba(33,153,232,0.8);
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

Here's my component code (not sure about the correct use of Ember.run.next (!)

```
// other component code here 

const {$} = Ember;

init() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  this.handleResize = function() {
    let itemWidth = $(".call-out-item img").width();
    let itemHeight = parseInt(itemWidth/1.5);
    $(".hover-mask").css({"width":itemWidth,"height":itemHeight});
  }.bind(this);
  Ember.run.next(this, this.handleResize); 
  $(window).on('resize', Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize));
},
// etc etc
```

I am getting variable results with this code in Chrome and Firefox so must be doing something wrong here!

Comment: Instead of `Ember.run.next`, you should override the `didInsertElement` element instead of `init`.


Ember docs [reference](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Component/events/didInsertElement?anchor=didInsertElement) : 
"Override [didInsertElement] to do any set up that requires an element in the document body"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you unbind the event when the component is destroyed, otherwise your event will continue to trigger while the user is on other routes

```
initResizeObserver: on("init", function () {
  $(window).on('resize', this.handleResize.bind(this));
}),

willDestroyElement () {
  this._super(...arguments);
  $(window).off("resize");
},

handleResize (e) {
  console.log(e)
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. One of the problems (in Firefox) was that the above code was not calculating the width of the image initially, so I am now calculating the width (and height) of the parent container and setting the dimensions of the image to 100% for width and height.

I still think there are some glitches when I resize the window (does anyone know why?) but I hope this helps!

```
// component code 

import Ember from 'ember';
const {$} = Ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName:'div',
  classNames:[],
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.handleResize = function() {
      let itemWidth = parseInt($(".call-out-item").width());
      let itemHeight = parseInt(itemWidth/1.5);
      $(".hover-mask").css({"width":itemWidth,"height":itemHeight});
   };
   Ember.run.next(this, this.handleResize);
   $(window).on('resize', Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize));
 },
 // rest of code
```